# Mensaje de WhatsAPP a php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, whatsapp

Hola Buen dia miren mi proyecto consiste en enviar un mensaje predeterminado al cliente para que pague por el servicio consegui un código en el cual a traves de una API de WhatsApp si me deja pero el problema es que solo me deja insertar un solo número de telefono me gustaria saber si podrian ayudarme o saben como enviar a mas de una persona y con el mismo mensaje predeterminado.
Mi código es el siguiente todo es atraves de un boton.

```
<center><br><img class="btn-whatsapp" src="https://clientes.dongee.com/whatsapp.png" a title="Contáctanos" width="28" height="28" onclick="window.location.href='https://wa.me/?texto=Hola' " > </center>
```

Al momento de ejecutar este codigo o darle clic en el boton me dirije al link que esta pero me dice que WhatsApp no esta instalado a pesar de que si y si le agrego un numero de telefono como ya antes dicho si me deja pero solo ese numero de telefono
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no creo que puedas ya que lo que pretendes es spam y no se si whatsapp lo permite

Comment: Bueno y si por ejemplo en vez de a mas personas sea a una sola persona pero tomando en cuenta la base de datos

Comment: Y cómo accedes a la base de datos? Qué información te muestra? Lo que estás usando no es propiamente una API, es sólo un enlace. La API oficial de WhatsApp es para clientes Business y tiene un acceso limitado, esta te permite más opciones de configuración sin necesidad de pasar por la app instalada en Windows. Revisa: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/using-the-api